# Writing a dask bag of data frame to disk (Generating 2 million features with dask and featuretools)

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, featuretools, feature-engineering

I'm very new to both Dask and Featuretools so I'm having alot of difficulties combining them to parallelize feature engineering

**Short version**: solving an immediate problem
I have a dask bag `dfs` of `pandas DataFrame` and want to output them as csv with each file having the partition as identifier. [to_textfiles()](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.Bag.to_textfiles) raised an error and I can't seem to find a way to get partition number to use `dfs.map(pd.to_csv, "[partition_num].csv")`. Is there a way to do this?

```
>>> dfs 
dask.bag<map-par..., npartitions=2>

>>> type(dfs.compute()[0])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

>>> dfs.to_textfiles('feature_matrices/calculate_matrix/*_test')

anaconda3/envs/featuretools/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/utils.py in ensure_unicode()
    592         return s.decode()
    593     msg = "Object %s is neither a bytes object nor has an encode method"
--> 594     raise TypeError(msg % s)

TypeError: ('Long error message', 'Object                 Age          ArrivalMethod\nPAT_ENC_CSN_ID                            \n3223775624       33                    Car\n3223776450       82         Medical Flight\n3223776487       65                  Other\n3223776543       31              Ambulance\n3223835687       89              Ambulance\n3223838474       42  Public Transportation\n3223842283       11              Ambulance\n3223845045       60              A
```

**Long version**: For those who are wondering why I have a dask bag of pandas dataframe, I'm putting my entire problem here in search of a better approach. I'm trying to use featuretools to generate 2 million features for a dataset of 22k rows (for feature selection later). I'm trying to follow the references ([this post](https://medium.com/feature-labs-engineering/scaling-featuretools-with-dask-ce46f9774c7d) and [this notebook](https://github.com/Featuretools/Automated-Manual-Comparison/blob/master/Loan%20Repayment/notebooks/Featuretools%20on%20Dask.ipynb)). In the notebook, the data set was huge (45 million rows) and much bigger than my 22k row dataset.

Nevertheless, I did split mine into partitions of 741 rows, since passing the `entity set` of full data to [calculate_feature_matrix](https://docs.featuretools.com/generated/featuretools.computational_backends.calculate_feature_matrix.html#featuretools.computational_backends.calculate_feature_matrix) had a sequential component that took too long (probably to to distribute the `entity set` to workers). This happens even if I only generate one feature with the entire dataset. None of my `dask-workers` ([LSFCluster](https://dask-jobqueue.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/dask_jobqueue.LSFCluster.html)) had more than 5% CPU utilization after 20 minutes of running `calculate_matrix` and it resulted in a huge trackback of errors:

*Using entire dataset with one feature:*

```
...
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/featuretools/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/featuretools/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 249, in accept_handler
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/featuretools/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 205, in accept
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
Exception in callback BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(110, 1)
handle: <Handle BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(110, 1)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/featuretools/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/lab/corradin_data/FOR_AN/anaconda3/envs/featuretools/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/featuretools/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/featuretools/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 249, in accept_handler
  File "path/anaconda3/envs/featuretools/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 205, in accept
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

In addition to splitting the dataset, I also split by features, doing one feature at a time. I now want to write the feature to disk, but want to combine them into 1k chunks instead of outputting 2 mil csv files. Below is my approach so far, which ends up with dfs being a `dask bag` of `pandas DataFrame`

*For each partition of 741 rows, calculate one feature at a time*:

```
from dask_jobqueue import LSFCluster
from dask.distributed import Client
cluster = LSFCluster(...)
client = Client(cluster)

# take a feature, return a feature matrix for a subset of data
def make_feature(feature):
    feature_name = feature.generate_name()
    try:
        feature_matrix = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(feature, entityset=es, n_jobs= 1, verbose = 1) #es is one partition of dataset

        print(f"Finished generating feature {feature_name}")
        return feature_matrix
    except:
        print(f"Could not make feature: {feature_name}")
        print("--------")
        return None

import dask.bag as db
b = db.from_sequence(feature_list, partition_size=1000) # 1k feature per partition
b = b.map(make_feature) 

#concatenate 1k dataframe (1 partition) to 1 df 
def concat(partition):
    series = [i for i in partition]
    df = pd.concat(series,axis =1)
    return [df]

dfs = b.map_partitions(concat) # dask bag of dataframes

overall_start = timer()
dfs.compute()
overall_end = timer()

print(f"Total Time Elapsed: {round(overall_end - overall_start, 2)} seconds.")

#ouput to disk here
???
```

It's my first SO question so please let me know what to fix/add for my question to be clearer. Thanks!